# Is it possible to change the step size of the built-in haskell range function or literal?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, range

The default

```
[1..5]
```

gives this

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and can also be done with the range function. Is it possible to change the step size between the points, so that I could get something like the following instead?

```
[1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
[1,1.5..5]
```

Comment: Can you go backwards with this? I.e. can you go from 5 .. 1 in decrements of 0.5?

Comment: Followup: Tried [5,4.5,1] and it works perfectly. Goes from 5.0 to 1.0 in decrements of 0.5.

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally You mean `[5,4.5..1]`

Answer (score 18):

You have to be careful with floating point arithmetic.  It can't represent 1.1 precisely, so if you try

```
Prelude> [0,0.1 .. 1]
[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.30000000000000004,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.7999999999999999,0.8999999999999999,0.9999999999999999]
```

Best way is more like:

```
Prelude> map (/10) [0..10]
[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually, `[1..5]` is syntactic sugar for

```
enumFromTo 1 5
```

and `[1,1.5..5]` for

```
enumFromThenTo 1 1.5 5
```

For more information, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Syntactic_sugar

Answer (score 2):

I just want to elaborate on some of the answers above. As @mattiast correctly mentioned,

`[start, abs(start - stepSize) .. end]` is really just syntactic sugar for:

`enumFromThenTo start abs(start - stepSize) end`

However, notice that the middle value (in your case, the "1.5" is **not** the step size, but what *the value should be* were its magnitude from the start to be computed.

So if you want to *decrement* in steps of 0.2, then we would need to do `[2,1.8..1]` since `abs(2 - 1.8) == 0.2`